# QListWidget::itemChanged signal triggered twice in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

I have a `QListWidget` to store usernames, and I use this signal to detect if username is being changed:

```
connect(listWidget, &QListWidget::itemChanged, this, &MainWindow::changeUserName);

void MainWindow::changeUserName(QListWidgetItem *editItem)
{
    qDebug() << "Name:" << editItem->text();
}
```

And this is how I make `QListWidget` editable in another function:

```
connect(listWidget, &QListWidget::itemDoubleClicked, this, &MainWindow::makeListEditable);

void MainWindow::makeListEditable()
{
    QListWidgetItem *editItem = listWidget->currentItem();
    editItem->setFlags(editItem->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
    qDebug() << "Name edit";
}
```

But which confused me is, whenever I double clicked the list widget, the `itemChanged` signal will be triggered once, and when I input a new username, the signal will be triggered again. Why would this happen?

This is the debug output, when I double clicked the list, it says:

```
Name: "Testing name_1"
Name edit
```

after I entered a new name and hit the enter, it says:

```
Name: "Testing name_2" //a new name I changed to
```

And what if I only want a signal be triggered once whenever I input a new name and hit the enter, what should I do to achieve this? 
Thanks

Comment: please show a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc Ok, I edit that.

Comment: Well, when you double-click, you *change* the flags of your item, so this item *has changed* in a way, right ? You may be looking for something that looks more like *itemTextChanged* (not sure if this one exists though). After a quick look, there is *currentTextChanged* signal -- http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#currentTextChanged

Comment: @Rafalon Yes, an `itemTextChanged` signal is what I am looking for, but it does not exist. What I want to achieve there is to detect if the text of the item has been changed. Unfortunately, I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Isn't *currentTextChanged* what you are looking for ?

Comment: @Rafalon I tried that signal out before and after you left a comment, but somehow this signal will only emit once whenever my program starts, and later when I try to change its name, the signal will not be emitted.

Comment: @Rafalon the debug out put is `Name: "Testing name_1"(when the program started)
Name edit(when I double clicked the list to change its name)
Name edit`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the item delegate `commitData` signal, this way:

```
QObject::connect(listWidget->itemDelegate(), SIGNAL(commitData(QWidget*)), this, SLOT(dataCommited(QWidget*)));
```

the slot is like this:

```
void dataCommited(QWidget * w)
{
    QString data = (static_cast<QLineEdit *>(w))->text();
    //...
}
```

The signal will be emitted at the end of the editing (i.e. enter key pressed or focus lost etc.)

Answer (score 0):

As @Rafalon said, calling setFlags calls your slot changeUserName, and the signal *currentTextChanged* is emitted when the current item changed, it is the same as *currentItemChanged* except it gives you the text instead of the item.

What you can do is, make your item editable as you instantiate it:

```
QListWidgetItem* pItem = new QListWidgetItem();
pItem->setText("Testing name_1");
pItem->setFlags(pItem->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
listWidget->addItem(pItem);
```

or you can activate/deactivate the connection when you need it:

```
void MainWindow::makeListEditable(QListWidgetItem *editItem)
{
    editItem->setFlags(editItem->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
    connect(ui->listWidget, SIGNAL(itemChanged(QListWidgetItem *)), this, SLOT(changeUserName(QListWidgetItem *)));
    qDebug() << "Name edit";
}
void MainWindow::changeUserName(QListWidgetItem *editItem)
{
    qDebug() << "Name:" << editItem->text();
    disconnect(ui->listWidget, SIGNAL(itemChanged(QListWidgetItem *)), this, SLOT(changeUserName(QListWidgetItem *)));
}
```

but you will have to make another connection when the current element is not modified after a double click, maybe with the signal *currentItemChanged*.